# Ant can't find my JAR file? Trying to do an sshexec task

Tags: java, deployment, ant

I'm trying to use the sshexec task for ANT on my OSX box, when I try to run it I get the error listed below. I've downloaded the jsch jar file from: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/index.html version jsch-0.1.43.jar

I placed that file into /usr/share/ant/lib and still the error occurs. any ideas?

thanks

```
<target name="testme" depends="">
 <sshexec host="myhost1" username="${username}" command="ls -la" keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa" />
</target>
```

I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/jim/Code/myapp/deploy.xml:16: Problem: failed to create task or type sshexec
Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec was not found.
        This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/Users/jim/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument

Do not panic, this is a common problem.
The commonest cause is a missing JAR.
```

UPDATE::::
I installed a new version of ANT from apache and put it in /usr/local and moved the jsch file into /usr/local/ant/lib and it fixes the error, however now I have a new one when I run it with: ant -f deploy.xml restart

```
BUILD FAILED
    /Users/jim/Code/myapp/deploy.xml:20: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec.setExtOutputStream(Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.executeCommand(SSHExec.java:265)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.execute(SSHExec.java:194)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Here is my diagnostic information:

http://pastebin.org/877058

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like a version compatibility issue, check the version of jsch matches the one supported by the ant version.

Comment: I installed version: jsch-0.1.42.jar just in case based on the docs at: http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies but I'm still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem, when trying to fix the old ant version I had this file left over from my debugging attempts:
/Library/Java/Extensions/jsch-0.1.8.jar

I removed that guy and all is well

Comment: since i was right, you should probably tick my answer and move your post to a comment. that would be the correct SO thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Download `jsch-0.1.44.jar` and make sure `trust="true"` is set.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you give trust="true"

```
<sshexec trust="true"
           host="host_ip"        
           verbose="true/false"
           username="UserName"
           keyfile="KeyFile_location"                     
           command="some_command">
</sshexec>
```