# ANT can't find specific libraries

Tags: java, ant, jsch

I am trying to use the [SSHEXEC ANT task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html), which requires the [JSCH library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

When I try to use an `SSHEXEC` task, I get the following:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/www/test/build/build.xml:140: Problem: failed to create task or type sshexec
Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec was not found.
        This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/root/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument

Do not panic, this is a common problem.
The commonest cause is a missing JAR.

This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem
```

I have placed `jsch-0.1.50.jar` (the latest) in `/usr/share/ant/lib`, `/root/.ant/lib` and even tried the following:

```
ant my-sshexec-target-name -lib /path/to/jsch-0.1.50.jar
```

And I keep getting the same error. I have also tried renaming the file to simply `jsch.jar` in all the same locations. Same result. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Also I ran `ant -diagnostics` and see this:

```
...
-------------------------------------------
 Tasks availability
-------------------------------------------
p4reopen : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
image : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
sshexec : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
wlrun : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
p4label : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
p4revert : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
p4submit : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
scp : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
p4change : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
p4delete : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
p4integrate : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
rexec : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
stlist : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
telnet : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)
etc...
```

Note: **sshexec : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)**

What does that mean?

Comment: Hey Jake what was the answer?  Nothing in this thread is helping.

Answer (score 1):

on my Linux Mint Debian Edition 2 I faced the same problem: Wondering why "sshexec" task is stated as "Not available" when executing "ant -diagnostics".

Solution on my system was to install package "ant-optional" additionally. After that the usual solutions work as expected, like putting jsch.jar to ~/.ant/lib.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the jar is there on the classpath by printing CLASSPATH varible in unix

Comment: `echo $CLASSPATH` doesn't give me anything... Also I updated my question with more info.

Comment: the variable is not at all printing any values or your jar is not there in that?

Comment: No value to the variable. Just a blank line in the terminal.

Comment: It clearly says 'sshexec : Not Available (the implementation class is not present)'.Ideally it is quiet strange. Try change the location of the jar file and add it

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721890/ant-cant-find-my-jar-file-trying-to-do-an-sshexec-task

Answer (score 0):

Set ANT_HOME to /usr/share/ant/

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant/
```